# Zero or indefinite article

Tags: zero-article, legalese

Here are the examples where zero articles are used:

> This is a tenant’s notice which does not have to be **in statutory prescribed form** but there is an example of how such a notice could be worded at…. The s.26 request has to be **in statutory prescribed form**, an example of which is given at … The s.25 notice has to be **in statutory prescribed form**. An example of a hostile notice is given at…

Below are sentences, where ‘a’ is used:

> The s.26 request must be **in a prescribed form**. The tenant’s proposed terms for the new lease must either be attached to or inserted in the schedule to the s.26 request. Both a ‘hostile’ and a ‘friendly’ s.25 notice must be **in a prescribed form** and pre-printed versions are available for use. If prescribed information is omitted, the s.25 notice may be held to be invalid.

To be honest, in the first group of the examples, I would used the indefinite article before 'statutory prescribed form'. I cannot understand why this expression is used with zero article, while the words 'in a prescribed form' use the indefinite article.

Would you please explain the reason for using zero article and indefinite article in the examples and whether meaning is different?

Rgrds

Comment: Are either of these examples from a legal document?  Legal documents are notorious for not using articles.  Legal grammar is *very different* from what someone might call "everyday run-of-the-mill English grammar."

Comment: **Form** can be used in different senses. **In a form...** refers to a single item. **In this form....** can be understood to mean **in this manner**. If you interpret your example in the second sense, no article is required. You are simply replacing **this** with **statutory prescribed**

Comment: These are not from a legal document, but from a textbook for law students.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're seeing is a legal text which is using a legal style of speech where zero articles are common. But most people, even lawyers, have no idea that there is such a thing as a zero article, and as a result they are not consistent with using it or the standard indefinite article.

That said, I do think you are looking at too different uses of "form". One is the talking about the "prescribed *manner*" in which notices should be given (eg form of words). The other is talking about a printed "form" that someone has to fill in. You can't use zero articles with that sort of noun.

> complete in statutory form.
>
> complete the statutory form.

These two commands mean *very* different things.

Comment: Hmm... All the quoted sentences in the question seem to use the word "form" in the second meaning you refer to.that is, a template, not a manner.

Comment: Re-reading, I partly agree with you. They all have the same meaning, but it's the first that is being indicated: "in [a] statutory prescribed manner/way". They've simply been inconsistent about including/excluding the article. To say "in statutory prescribed template" would be an error I don't believe the author would have made. The distinction in meaning is very slight between an abstract legal form (zero article works) and a concrete legal form (zero article does not work) in this context, but I do believe it's there.